# 'scl enable' not setting PATH with bash

Tags: bash, software-collections

I'm trying to use software collections on CentOS 6.8 server, but it won't set the environment variable PATH corectly if the command passed is "bash", but "tcsh" works... (however we don't use tcsh on this machine)

Example:

```
$ scl --list
devtoolset-4
python27
rh-java-common
rh-perl524
rh-python35
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
$ scl enable python27 bash
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
$ cat /opt/rh/python27/enable 
export PATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export MANPATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}
# For systemtap
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}
# For pkg-config
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/pkgconfig${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}}
$ echo $PATH
/usr/share/gridengine/bin/lx26-amd64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/maker/bin:/opt/tools/:/opt/tools/amos-3.1.0:/opt/mpich-install/bin:/opt/pssc/bin:/opt/torque/bin:/opt/torque/sbin
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64
$ echo $MANPATH
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/share/man::/opt/mpich-install/share/man:/opt/mpich-install/share/man
```

So why is `MANPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being set properly but not `PATH`?  If i use tcsh it works as expected:

```
$ scl enable python27 tcsh
$ which python
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

Comment: Perhaps there are modifications to PATH in your local `.bashrc` or global `/etc/bashrc` that override the value, rather than appending. There are a number of non-standard paths listed that suggest config modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Dominic you were on to something.  I originally checked `~/.bash*` files as well as `/etc/bash*` and `/etc/profile` but after your comment, I found several scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` that we being executed, and one of them set the PATH explicitly without appending.  I added `$PATH` back in there and now `scl enable` is working as expected!